# How to check if the textinputs are not empty in registration form? React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I'm a new React Native developer. I made a registration form using React Native, Redux and Firebase now I want to check if all fields are not empty before the user sign up, and if the user put a valid email format
Here's the code:

```
 export class Register extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
             super(props);
    
             this.state = { 
                 email: '',
                 password: '',
                 name: '',
                 lastname: ''
             }
    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
    
         }
    onSignUp(){
        const { email, password, name } = this.state;
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Users")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    name,
                    email
                })
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
        render() {
            return (
               <View  style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent:'center' }}>
                    <TextInput
                   placeholder="name"
                   onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
    
                   />
                   <TextInput
                   placeholder="email"
                   onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
    
                   />
                   <TextInput
                   placeholder="password"
                   secureTextEntry={true}
                   onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
    
                   />
                  <Button 
                  onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                  title= 'Sign Up'
                  />
               </View>
            )
        }
    }
    export default Register
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    onSignUp(){
        if(
            this.state.email != '' &&
            this.state.password != '' &&
            this.state.name != ''
        ){
            const { email, password, name } = this.state;
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((result) => {
                firebase.firestore().collection("Users")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    name,
                    email
                })
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
        else{
            alert("fill the empty spaces!");
        }
```

Comment: Worked well, just delete the extra *&&* after *this.state.name != ''* thanks man

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like,

```
if(name === '')
{
 Alert.alert("name is required")
}
else if(email === '')
{
 Alert.alert("email is required")
}
else if(password === '')
{
 Alert.alert("password is required")
}
else
{
 //call your API here
}
```

Comment: I would also use .trim() functions to check if a User just puts a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic if-else statements like this:

```
if (name === "") {
  console.log("Please Enter Name")
} else if (email === "") {
  console.log("Please Enter E-Mail") 
} else if (password === "") {
  console.log("Please Enter Password")
} else {
  // Sign Up
}
```

Or you can also use Regular Expressions to be even more precise:

```
if (/\w{4}/.test(name)) {
  console.log("Name must have at least 4 characters")
} else if (/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
  console.log("Please enter a valid email")
} else if (/\w{8}/.test(password)) {
  console.log("Password must have at least 8 characters")
} else {
  //Sign up
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
if(name.trim() === ''){
  alert("name is required")
}
```

.trim() remove extra white-spaces,